# Changing a variable within a class causes global variables to change as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.array([[2.,3.,4.],[5.,6.,7.,]])

class TTESt:

    def __init__(self,weight_new):
        self.weight_new = weight_new

    def changeweights(self):

        temp = np.zeros(shape = (2,3))
        temp_weights = self.weight_new
        temp_weights[0,0] = 1000.

        return temp_weights

aaa = TTESt(weights)
aaa.changeweights()
print(weights)
```

I expected the output of `print(weights)` to be `np.array([[2.,3.,4.],[5.,6.,7.,]])` (remains itself).

But it is not.

The output of this code is:

```
[[1000.    3.    4.]
 [   5.    6.    7.]]
[[1000.    3.    4.]
 [   5.    6.    7.]]
```

Why the global variable `weights` changes? I did not assign a new value to it.

What could I do to avoid this problem from coming up again?

Thank you!

Comment: `temp_weights` is the same array object that you initially called `weights`  The `=` assignment doesn't make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, there is no concept of "pass by reference" or "pass by value". Everything is "pass by *name*". That said, there is a difference between passing *mutable* and *immutable* objects.

You are passing the global `weights`, a mutable object, to the class constructor. Since it's mutable, it's sort of analogous to passing by reference. The scope in which you modify the object does not matter. Whether you use the name in the scope of the class (`self.weights_new`) or the name in the global scope (`weights`), the object is the same.

If you instead pass and modify an *immutable* object like a tuple, it will behave more like "pass by value".